# Merge objects in a foreach loop

Tags: php

I have the need to merge the objects getting returned from a foreach loop. Below are examples of the objects getting returned. I have searched high and low and cannot find any specific answers anywhere to this particular issue.

Here is my foreach loop

```
foreach ( $instagram_basic->data as $media ) {
        $media_id = $media->id;
        $instagram_basic_data_array['data'] = 'https://graph.instagram.com/$media_id ...;
        $instagram_basic_media_response = $this->fts_get_feed_json( $instagram_basic_data_array );
        $instagram_basic_media = json_decode( $instagram_basic_media_response['data'] );
        print_r( $instagram_basic_media );
}
```

Here are the results when using print_r. note: there will always be more than 2 objects returned, I only added 2 below as an example.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [caption] => Arcade1Up Plexiglass cover installed!
    [id] => 17914463977383922
)

stdClass Object
(
    [caption] => #ninamilesmacey
    [id] => 17907886372351359
)
```

I would like the end result to look like this.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [caption] => Arcade1Up Plexiglass cover installed!
                        [id] => 17914463977383922
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [caption] => #ninamilesmacey
                        [id] => 17907886372351359
                    )
        )
)
```

Maybe there is a more efficient way for me to merge the arrays before I jason decode them too? Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you json_decode with passing the second parameter **TRUE**, the object converts to array and you can use array merge functions to get merge these arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create the basis of your data before the loop, then add each item as you go along, this should give you the output you are after...

```
$output = (object)['data' => []];
foreach ( $instagram_basic->data as $media ) {

// Other code here


        $output->data[] = $instagram_basic_media ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! How can I retain the stdClass Object ( [data] => Array (... portion at the start of return?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, `print_r($output);` should show all of the structure.

Comment: aye, just had to remove the ->data part on my print_r. You rock, thanks again!